# Get JavaScript to relinquish CPU so that browser can apply new stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css

Upon loading, my web site runs this code if the users is using an alternate theme:

```
ReplaceJSCSSFile("css/skin1.css", "css/skin2.css", "css");
AJAX_LoadResponseIntoElement("skinContainer", "skin" + themeSelect + ".txt", function() {
    AJAX_LoadResponseIntoElement("contentdiv", "index.txt", initPage);
    });
```

What AJAX_LoadResponseIntoElement does ought to be obvious, but here's a short explanation of ReplaceJSCSSFile:  It basically searches for `link` elements within the web page with their `src` property equal to *"css/skin1.css"*, at which point it creates a new `link` element (*src="css/skin2.css"*) and uses `.parentNode.replaceChild` to replace the old with the new.

The problem with this is that `initPage()` sets the positions and of certain divs that move around on the screen in relation to the positions of static elements.  The position of those static elements is fetched from CSS, but the CSS is not being applied before the code is running, and `initPage()` is putting things in the wrong place because of it.

I have tried using a callback:

```
ReplaceJSCSSFile("css/skin1.css", "css/skin2.css", "css", function() {
    AJAX_LoadResponseIntoElement("skinContainer", "skin" + themeSelect + ".txt", function() {
        AJAX_LoadResponseIntoElement("contentdiv", "index.txt", initPage);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work.  Presumably, it tells the browser to replace the CSS file, and as soon as it tells the browser to do that, it moves on to the callback function, using AJAX to fetch the page contents.  I'm thinking the page contents come back prior to the CSS file, which is why the new CSS is not being applied by the time `initPage()` is being executed.

Is it possible to fix this without using alternate stylesheets?

The only thing that I can come up with other than alternate stylesheets is fetching the CSS contents with AJAX (which would actually wait for the server's response before executing the callback function) to replace the "*css/skin1.css*" `link` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fudge it and use `setTimeout` in your callback so that the body of the callback isn't run until a bit later. This gives the browser some time to recover.

Comment: This works... thanks.  I think what I'm going to do is make some sort of proceed() function.  It will basically just do a 10ms timeout until the CSS change has been detected.  I'll also try the AJAX solution that I mentioned in my OP.  For now, though, it's an adequate quick fix.  Thanks!